# Take an element from a website and put into an android app

Tags: android

Okay noob of the year question.

I have a website, which has several div. and one of those div I would like to put as the front end of an android app.

I.E, I have this div id 
I want to put that entire element as the android application.  Of course add buttons for it for various items, but right now that is my main obsticle.

I dont want to hard code the page into the android application, becuase of course that element changes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WebView to display a Website inside your application. See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). If you want to display only one div of a website, you could move this div to another page. This should be the easiest method to achieve your goal.

BTW: There are no stupid questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to code your site so that this DIV has a unique ID assigned to it. You could then download all of the HTML from your site into a string in your app, parse out this individual div you want (by finding the unique ID) and save it in a string named, say, html. Next you can place this DIV inside of a webview using webView.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding); where "html" is a string containing the div you extracted. So long as that DIV has content that has absolute paths to resources (images/links), it should load and display your content properly

Comment: Note that this is "somewhat" hard coding since you will always be relying on that DIV to have that specific unique ID. @Martin Matysiak's idea of having the div as a separate page would work well if you didn't want to do this.